# Append @ and print everthing after #

Tags: regex, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I have a string like

```
This a a home #ABCD-123 and this #EFGH-1233 #FGEH-123
```

I want a regex to print the following output

```
@ABCD-123 @EFGH-1233 @FGEH-123
```

The number of # can be varying 
I have #ABCD-111
should print only @ABCD-111

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @Solver shell scripting

Comment: `#[\w-]+` and then replace `#` with `@`. I'm not too familiar with bash, but it should resemble that.

Comment: If the `#`s only ever appear at the beginning of the strings in your input, all you have to do is replace `#` with `@`, no need for regex.

Comment: @CAustin the `#AAAA-111`s seem to be anywhere in the string

Comment: @anubhava if I use sed -E 's/#([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)/@\1/g' file  and the file contains  ia #John-11 #MA-16 the output is                                                  
`ia @John-11 @MA-16 I want the output to be @John-11 @MA-16`

Comment: @anubhava In this example This a a home #ABCD-123 and this #EFGH-1233 #FGEH-123 I am not printing This a a home, and this `I want only the characters after the pound

Comment: @Connor can you use grep command?
grep -Eo '#[-0-9a-zA-Z]+' inputfile | sed -E 's/#/@/g'

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oP '#\K\S+' <<<"$string" | sed 's/^/@/' | paste -s -d" "
```

will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, you can do:

```
awk '{p=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^#[^ \t]/) {
$i = "@" substr($i, 2); printf "%s%s", (p++?OFS:""), $i} if (p) print ""}' <<< "$ENVVAR"

@ABCD-123 @EFGH-1233 @FGEH-123
```

Comment: This works. How can I use an environment variable instead of a file

Comment: Yes sure, change `file` to `<<< "$ENVVAR"`

Comment: But having the value in a variable in the first place sounds like something you should perhaps look into changing. Whatever did `var="$(commands)"` in the first place can do `var="$(commands | awk this)"` as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `sed` variant which can inject newlines (most can, but the syntax may vary) why don't you simply

```
sed 's/\([^@#] \)*\([@#][-A-Z0-9]*\)/\2\n/g' <<<"$string"
```

The `\n` might not be produce a literal newline in your `sed`; maybe try

```
sed 'stuff ...\2\
/g' <<<"$string"
```

or [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48120271/edit) your question to add details about your specific OS (Linux or some other platform; if Linux, which distro; and which version of the `sed` package?) and we can take it from there.